# How to use jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, autocomplete

I have looked at many, many examples and cannot figure out to get the autocomplete to work.  Here is my HTML:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Item Number:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="items" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(x=>x.ItemDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ItemDescription, new { @id = "txtDescription" }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my C# code:

```
 public ActionResult GetAllItemNumbers(string data)
    {
        List<string> result = ItemLookup.GetAllItemNumbers(data);
        var result1 = result.Where(item => item.Contains(data)).ToList();
        return Json(result1);
    }
```

And here is the JS code:

```
 $("#items").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {data: request.term },
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllItemNumbers")',
                success: function (data) {
                    response = $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        };
                    });
                }
             });
        },
        minLength: 4
    });
```

The correct items are being selected and returned to the success function.  But there is no drop down being displayed.  How do you show the drop down of values that match the input?

Comment: Is your controller action marked with `[HttpPost]`? When you **debug** your code, does your controller action even get hit? Why aren't you specifying an input type for `#items`? Do you have a reference to jQuery and jQuery UI in your page?

Comment: Yes, the method is getting hit just fine, and the correct list of strings is getting returned to the page.  I just do not see the drop down results.

Comment: According to the [Autocomplete demos](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp), `response` is a callback function to which you should be *passing* your data (e.g. `response($.map(...))`).

Comment: I am mapping it, as you can see above, but what does that do?  How do you generate a drop down from that?

Comment: You are assigning the result of the `$.map` operation *to* `response`, instead of passing it as a parameter to `response` (it is a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Autocomplete demos](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp), `response` is a callback function to which you should be *passing* your data. I think you should change this line:

```
response = $.map(...);
```

to

```
response($.map(...));
```

The `response` method is what is responsible for building and showing the drop down. It takes the data returned from the controller. In your original code, you are overriding it, so effectively processing stops at that point, and you don't see the drop down being rendered.

Here is an excerpt from the above link for loading items from a remote data source (comments mine):

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data ); // pass data INTO response, don't assign it
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 3,
  // other methods omitted
});
```